# iptable rules not blocking

Tags: ssh, iptables

I am trying to allow SSH access to a certain range of IPs (from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.24`) and block all the rest, but since I am new to iptables I can't seem to figure it out.  I have :

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport ssh -j REJECT
```

Tut this does not work, with a VM set with `192.168.1.89` I can still access through SSH. Can someone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`192.168.1.0/24` is not from 1 to 24 but using 24 bits (= the 3 1st blocks) so it will accept anything starting with 192.168.1. The right one is /27 but it will allow up to 192.168.1.31.

The next smaller range will be /28 that will allow up to 192.168.1.15.

Comment: so how can i do this the proper way?

Comment: I was calculating that. Edited answer :)

Comment: If you use 28, you can allow from ....1 to ...15

Comment: found this calculator http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Answer (score 7):

/24 is the CIDR length, not a range.

To use a range, do this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.24 -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

The First DROP all INPUT Rullse ( For more security)
The Second :
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 22 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.24 -j ACCEPT
Have good time